# 2 wired Access points cause Internet to drop

Tags: internet-connection, wireless-access-point

I have a 6 point wired network with 2 routers set up as access points plugged into 2 of the network points. I also have a Sonos network with the bridge hardwired into one of the Access Points  This worked well for 3 years then suddenly my internet drops randomly but leaving router seemingly OK (all lights green.  I have to reboot the router than all is ok for a while

Now, if i take one of the access points off the network all is well, plugging into different network points has no effect.  Swapping hardware also has no effect

Anyone any clues, this is driving me nuts

Cheers

Peter Thompson